# Julia - map function status

Tags: parallel-processing, julia, anonymous-function, pmap

Is there a comfy way to somehow get the 'status' of map/pmap in Julia?

If I had an array a = [1:10] i'd like to either:

1: enumerate the array and use if-conditional to add a print command

```
((index,value) -> 5*value ......, enumerate(a)
```

and where the "......." are, there would be a way to 'chain' the anonymous function to something like

```
"5*value and then print index/length(a) if index%200 == 0"
```

2: know if there is already an existing option for this, as pmap is intended for parallel tasks, which are usually used for large processes so it would make sence for this to already exist?

Additionally, is there a way to make anonymous functions do two 'separate' things one after the other?

**Example**

if I have

```
a = [1:1000]
function f(n) #something that takes a huge ammount of time
end
```

and I execute

```
map(x -> f(x), a)
```

the REPL would print out the status

```
"0.1 completed"
.
.
.
"0.9 completed"
```

**Solution**

[Chris Rackauckas answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38769528/4551168)

A bitt odd that the ProgressMeter package doesnt include this by default

```
Pkg.add("ProgressMeter")
Pkg.clone("https://github.com/slundberg/PmapProgressMeter.jl")
@everywhere using ProgressMeter
@everywhere using PmapProgressmeter
pmap(x->begin sleep(1); x end, Progress(10), 1:10)
```

[PmapProgressMeter](https://github.com/slundberg/PmapProgressMeter.jl) on github

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by status. Please give an example of the output you want for a particular input vector.

Comment: 'status' as in how far through the evaluation, I posted an example to clarify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ProgressMeter.jl](https://github.com/timholy/ProgressMeter.jl) has a branch for pmap.

You can also make the Juno progress bar work inside of pmap. This is kind of using undocumented things, so you should ask in the [Gitter](https://gitter.im/JunoLab/Juno) if you want more information because posting this public will just confuse people if/when it changes.

Comment: nice catch of a probable [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) question :p

Comment: Excellent! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just include it in your function's definition to print this information?  E.g.

```
function f(n) #something that takes a huge amount of time
    ...
    do stuff.
    ...
    println("completed $n")
end
```

And, you can add an extra argument to your function, if desired, that would contain that `0.1`, ... , `0.9` in your example (which I'm not quite sure what those are, but whatever they are, they can just be an argument in your function).

If you take a look at the example below on `pmap` and `@parallel` you will find an example of a function fed to `pmap` that prints output.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38515624/julia-run-function-multiple-times-save-results-in-array/38516045#38516045) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24637064/julia-using-pmap-correctly?rq=1) SO post on info for feeding multiple arguments to functions used with `map` and `pmap`.

---

---

The Julia [documentation](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/parallel-computing/) advises that

> pmap() is designed for the case where each function call does a large amount of work. In contrast, @parallel for can handle situations where each iteration is tiny, perhaps merely summing two numbers.

There are several reasons for this.  First, `pmap` incurs greater start up costs initiating jobs on workers.  Thus, if the jobs are very small, these startup costs may become inefficient.  Conversely, however, `pmap` does a "smarter" job of allocating jobs amongst workers.  In particular, it builds a queue of jobs and sends a new job to each worker whenever that worker becomes available.  `@parallel` by contrast, divvies up all work to be done amongst the workers when it is called.  As such, if some workers take longer on their jobs than others, you can end up with a situation where most of your workers have finished and are idle while a few remain active for an inordinate amount of time, finishing their jobs.  Such a situation, however, is less likely to occur with very small and simple jobs.

The following illustrates this:  suppose we have two workers, one of which is slow and the other of which is twice as fast.  Ideally, we would want to give the fast worker twice as much work as the slow worker.  (or, we could have fast and slow jobs, but the principal is the exact same).  `pmap` will accomplish this, but `@parallel` won't.

For each test, we initialize the following:

```
addprocs(2)

@everywhere begin
    function parallel_func(idx)
        workernum = myid() - 1 
        sleep(workernum)
        println("job $idx")
    end
end
```

Now, for the `@parallel` test, we run the following:

```
@parallel for idx = 1:12
    parallel_func(idx)
end
```

And get back print output:

```
julia>     From worker 2:    job 1
    From worker 3:    job 7
    From worker 2:    job 2
    From worker 2:    job 3
    From worker 3:    job 8
    From worker 2:    job 4
    From worker 2:    job 5
    From worker 3:    job 9
    From worker 2:    job 6
    From worker 3:    job 10
    From worker 3:    job 11
    From worker 3:    job 12
```

It's almost sweet.  The workers have "shared" the work evenly.  Note that each worker has completed 6 jobs, even though worker 2 is twice as fast as worker 3.  It may be touching, but it is inefficient.

For for the `pmap` test, I run the following:

```
pmap(parallel_func, 1:12)
```

and get the output:

```
From worker 2:    job 1
From worker 3:    job 2
From worker 2:    job 3
From worker 2:    job 5
From worker 3:    job 4
From worker 2:    job 6
From worker 2:    job 8
From worker 3:    job 7
From worker 2:    job 9
From worker 2:    job 11
From worker 3:    job 10
From worker 2:    job 12
```

Now, note that worker 2 has performed 8 jobs and worker 3 has performed 4.  This is exactly in proportion to their speed, and what we want for optimal efficiency.  `pmap` is a hard task master - from each according to their ability.

Comment: You are right that's a good way to solve it. I had previously read (incorrectly) that pmap could only accept a function and a "single" vector as an arguement, which turned out to be incorrect so the problem is more or less solved this way by supplying an extra 'counting' vector to print out from

Comment: that function wouldn't be much good as an argument to pmap though ... probably best to pass a closure which automatically updates its state when called instead.

Comment: I suppose you could make it a two-argument function, and also pass an 'indices' array to map to keep track of items processed ... but again, this wouldn't be reliable for pmap, since it's not guaranteed to be sequential.

Comment: `pmap` (unlike `@parallal`) will feed arguments sequentially, it's just that the completion isn't guaranteed to be sequential.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function with 'state' as you ask, by implementing a 'closure'. E.g.

```
julia> F = function ()
  ClosedVar = 5
  return (x) -> x + ClosedVar
end;
julia> f = F();
julia> f(5)
10
julia> ClosedVar = 1000;
julia> f(5)
10
```

As you can see, the function `f` maintains 'state' (i.e. the internal variable `ClosedVar` is local to `F`, and `f` maintains access to it even though `F` itself has technically long gone out of scope.

Note the difference with normal, non-closed function definition:

```
julia> MyVar = 5;
julia> g(x) = 5 + MyVar;
julia> g(5)
10
julia> MyVar = 1000;
julia> g(5)
1005
```

You can create your own closure which interrogates / updates its closed variables when run, and does something different according to its state each time.

Having said that, from your example you seem to expect that `pmap` will run sequentially. This is not guaranteed. So don't rely on a 'which index is this thread processing' approach to print every 200 operations. You would probably have to maintain a closed 'counter' variable inside your closure, and rely on that. Which presumably also implies your closure needs to be accessible `@everywhere`

Answer (score 0):

One other possibility would be to use a `SharedArray` as a counter shared amongst the workers.  E.g.

```
addprocs(2)

Counter = convert(SharedArray, zeros(Int64, nworkers()))

## Make sure each worker has the SharedArray declared on it, so that it need not be fed as an explicit argument
function sendto(p::Int; args...)
  for (nm, val) in args
    @spawnat(p, eval(Main, Expr(:(=), nm, val)))
  end
end

for (idx, pid) in enumerate(workers())
  sendto(pid, Counter = Counter)
end
@everywhere global Counter


@everywhere begin
    function do_stuff(n)
        sleep(rand())
        Counter[(myid()-1)] += 1
        TotalJobs = sum(Counter)
        println("Jobs Completed = $TotalJobs")
    end
end

pmap(do_stuff, 1:10)
```

Comment: I've actually tried that very same thing, but it felt a bit complex and I wanted a simpler solution. However, I've never been able to get workers that I've assigned to SharedArray types, to actually be able to access the array, I see now that they need to be declared global. Parallelism in julia is hard

Comment: @isebarn Yeah, the parallelism stuff is a bit tricky to get used to.  I'm working on building up the SO documentation on it, but there's still a decent bit more I haven't gotten to.  The global declaration actually isn't the requirement here - instead, it is the `sendto` operation.  Global just makes the arguments global on each worker so that it's a bit easier and quicker for the function to know where to look for them, but it will find them eventually even without that.